# Using filters inside a ternary operator in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ternary-operator

Is there a method for applying a filter to a variable in the template when it is part of a ternary operation?

```
<img ng-src="{{ image_url && image_url|filter:"foo" || other_url }}">
```

In this case the filter is a custom filter, but one that I don't want to modify to handle the ternary operation (because the filter maybe different depending on where it's used and I don't want to reimplement that logic a bunch of times).

Comment: To me this looks too complex to be inline. I would create a function that will return the src based on whatever logic you need it to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Liviu T. is probably right in most cases: you'd want to create a function on the scope that returns the right data for you in this case.

That said, you can get by by wrapping the filtered expression in parens:

```
image_url && (image_url | filter:"foo") || other_url
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxpVw/1/)